# Access preview api from a CMS in Next.js

Tags: content-management-system, next.js

I was reading about the preview mode in [next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/preview-mode#securely-accessing-it-from-your-headless-cms) and i read the section about accessing the preview api either manually or from a CMS. I cant figure out how to access via a headless CMS.

Is something like a proxy? If yes, can someone show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing about proxy. From my experience in using Preview Mode with Sanity.io, the process goes like this:

1. In the Next.js side, you create an API route that can a) set some cookies on the user's browser which enables preview mode and b) redirect the user to the desired page based on the query string. When the data fetching methods(`getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths`) in Next.js pages see the `preview` flag enabled, they will bypass any static generation and render the page at request time instead of build time.

```
https://yourdomain.com/api/preview
```

2. In the CMS side, you construct the preview URL query string based on the document in view (and add a token string for security purposes). With Sanity, you can use a plugin to help you with that.

```
function resolvePreviewUrl(document) {
  return `https://yourdomain.com/api/preview?slug=${document.slug.current}&token=${process.env.PREVIEW_SECRET}`
}
```

3. Then in the CMS side, you can use the resolved preview URL however you want. You can either create a button that when clicked, open a new browser tab and bring the user to the preview API route, or create an iframe with `src` pointing to the preview URL.

References:

- [Next Preview
  Mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/preview-mode)
- [Preview API
  route](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/cms-sanity/pages/api/preview.js)
- [Sanity Preview Content on
  Studio](https://www.sanity.io/docs/preview-content-on-site)

Comment: What is a CMS and how can i access it? If you return the constructed url with the secret token , wont it be visible to browser?

Comment: CMS stands for Content Management System and yes in this implementation, the CMS user has access to the token. Such token prevents people who don’t have access to the CMS from accessing preview URLs. [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/preview-mode#securely-accessing-it-from-your-headless-cms)

Comment: How prevents people? If the url is visible, anyone can hit it in the navigation bar and get the preview api

Comment: It is true that with this approach, anyone who has access to the CMS can get the preview URL and the token. Next.js provides you a method setPreviewData to enable preview mode and you can use different authentication methods you see fit in the API route. The suggested approach would be good enough if there is not much "secret" in the preview data.

Comment: Sorry for the many posts but i still dont get how to use  cms in this scenario. We have the next.js endpoint api which sets the preview cookies and redirects you to the specified draft. How do you call this endpoint? From the browser? Where you hit the preview api url in navigation which contains the secret token?  From a proxy server, in this case the CMS? Do we call the CMS ourselves and then it makes an http request to  the next.js endpoint?

Comment: Take Sanity(one of the headless CMSs) as an example, it is just a single page application built with React for users to manage content, e.g. blog post. So in a blog post editing page, there could be an anchor tag or button that directs the user to the preview URL. This happens entirely on the client-side (in this case, the React app of Sanity). Sanity has a plugin to add such button for you but since the purpose of these headless CMSs is to create your own UI, you can do whatever you want with that preview URL, e.g. a tag, button, iframe, etc.

Comment: To better understand the flow (especially if you are new to the concept of headless CMS), you may follow this [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-sanity) to try the setup. They have detailed instructions in the "configuration" section.